# Auto-layout issue

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image: constraints]

I have a view with two button. I have added auto-layout. But bottom space is more in iPhone 8 plus than iPhone 4s.I want to keep the spacing ratio of top and bottom same in all iPhone. How to fix it ?

[image: iPhone 4s]
[image: iPhone 8 plus]

Comment: Did you add constraints to the container?

Comment: You should have constraints from the bottom and not the top.

Comment: You should probably set the constraints of the buttons relativly to the bottom and not the top.

Comment: yes,i have added constraints

Comment: Would you add a picture of the view hierarchy and another of your constraints?

Comment: show your constraints

Comment: you have to give constraint to button from bottom

Comment: And your constraints should not be on the buttons. You want to nest stackViews within each other. The constraints should only be on the stackViews themselves. Then you set the properties of the stackViews to have "centered" or "equal spacing"

Comment: when i add constraints from bottom, more space is remaining in top side...

Comment: then where you want to place your button on screen ??

Comment: I share the constraints

Comment: I want to keep the ratio same in all iPhone. is it possible ?

Comment: I will recommend you to study more about autolayouts. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ https://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Comment: @Md.MostafizurRahmanMafi , I posted my answer with UIStackview. U can check it. Any queries , let me know

Comment: I updated answer again.

Comment: What do you mean by the same ratio - are the supposed to be centered?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ not to be centered actually. I want to keep the ratio same in all iPhone. Like  2:1.

Comment: You should specify that explicitly in the question to avoid confusion.. are you working storyboards only, or do you use code too?

Comment: Depends, sometimes use storyboards, sometimes use code.

Comment: Can u show screenshot? how do u ned exactly ?

Comment: I updated again. I dont know, is this right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

For Specific Ratio : To my understood, We can give Multiplier for `Centre Vertically Constraints`. Here ratio of top and bottom space will be same in all iPhone series. I gave Multiplier as `1.4`

[image]

==================================

I know having several answers there. But, no one used `UIStackView` to add two simple buttons.

Drag two UIButton, select that two UIButtons, click `Embed in Stack` icon from here.

[image]

**Stackview Properties**

Give following things for UIStackView,

Set `Axis` as `Horizontal`, `Distribution` as `Fill Equally`, `Spacing` as `10` in `Attributes Inspector`

[image]

**Stackview Constraints 1**

Give constraints for that UIStackView, Check/Uncheck Margins, Left and Right = 0, Height as 30.

[image]

**Stackview Constraints 2**

Still, some constraints are not satisfied. Press `Control` and hold it, Click `StackView` and Drag to `SuperView`, you will get black pop up. Choose `Center Vertically in container`.

[image]

**Stackview Constraints Customization**

If you want to change height of UIButton or Bottom Space, click UIStackView and in `Size Inspector`, you can change height or move up/down.

[image]

Comment: you do realize that while it is related to the question, this does not really answer his question?

Comment: I just told, basic use of UIStackView.

Comment: yeah, but your answer is off-topic

Comment: This is not total wrong. I dnt knw why down vote? By this way also we can achieve tht.

Comment: 1. I haven't downvoted it (yet), someone else must agree with me. 2. You can achieve the same result the question has, but the answer itself does NOT answer what the question asks about. It is off-topic. The question asks about the relative position of the buttons to the superview, not about their layout. By this answer you are spamming the question with answer that is about something ELSE than the problem the question asks about. While I agree with you that using stackView to group these buttons is a good idea, again, it is NOT the question here.

Comment: **I want to keep the spacing ratio of top and bottom same in all iPhone. How to fix it ?** . He asked, center in all layout. I think, i have not read edited question. I wil edit my answer soon.

Comment: i updated my answer. @MilanNosáľ . Let me know, if anythin.

Comment: still, there is the main thing missing.. he wants to keep the space ratio between the top and bottom space between buttons and superview

Comment: here, top and bottom spaces are same

Comment: he does not want it centered, he wants to keep the ratio the same for all screen size (looks like it's 4:1)

Comment: No, his expectation is center i think.. How am Saying this , he is beginner, in his question, he gave top as 250 for each buttons, no bottom constraints. Then he tries to run, he got 4s bottom space  will be less when compare with other devices. So, he is asking, ratio of top and bottom space should be same.

Comment: well.. we can argue as much as we want - I guess the real answer can be provided by he himself only

Comment: Ok.. let see.. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Auto layout then set constraint like this way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

set constraints to bottom and leave top constraints

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 stack views. One Horizontal that contains the 2 buttons, and another vertical that contains the previous stack view. Set the horizontal stack view to "fill" and "equal spacing" and the vertical stack view to "fill" and "equal centering." Below I've included a couple of pictures to illustrate what I mean.

THE ONLY CONSTRAINTS ARE ON THE STACK VIEWS THAT BIND THEM TO THE SIZE OF THE CONTAINER VIEW, OR PARENT STACK VIEW.

This allows you to truly create an auto layout that scales with the device's screen size.

[image: NestedStackViews]

[image: Properties of Stack View]

[image]

Comment: Tust me, this is the way to go. Here is a free course to help you learn it. https://www.udacity.com/course/auto-layout--ud1026

Answer (score 0):

1) Select both buttons

2) Click on "Resolve auto-layout issues" button on bottom and click on "Reset to selected Constraints"

[image]

Comment: This will not give exact result in every scenario...!!! **jignesh Vadadoriya** , answer will give exact result. Better Use StackView to avoid more constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Use Constraints like this. These buttons have bottom fix with superview.

[image: User Constraints like this]