# Auto layout issue for devices in the same family and orientation

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm working on my beginner app and checked on the preview option for my app. I've noticed that across the iPhone X, 8+, 8 and SE the spacing of my objects are off. I've learned about the custom size class for various devices for different orientations but nothing what said about the same device family in the same orientations (ex: iPhones in portrait mode). This is what I am seeing.

[image]

The iPhone X looks fine but the others, not so much. I'm guessing that instead of using hard numbers for auto layout I should be using a ratio based on the height and width relative to the screen. Is that right?

Comment: We need to know your constraints, what you are trying to accomplish and what you are experiencing.  Sometimes fixed numbers make sense, sometimes ratios make sense, sometimes it makes sense to layout a certain number of points from the top or bottom etc.  We need more info.

Comment: @rMickeyD what is the best way to show the constraints for all those elements since there is 7 things on that screen

Comment: I have update my answer. It may give some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take Base `ViewController` as `iPhone4S`. Drag `UIView` called as `HolderView`, which should hold that `UILabel` and `Two UIViews`.

As per Design, give `HolderView's` width and height be same. Like `Square shape`.

Give Constraints as, `left` and `right` as 20px, `CenterHorizontally` and `CenterVertically`, and finally give `AspectRatio` to itself.

**HolderView**

[image]

Add `UIView` for `UILabel` to `HolderView` called as `LabelHolderView`.

Give constraints for `LabelHolderView` as `left` and `right` 20px, `CenterVertically` and `Height` as 90px (approx - Two lines for UILabel)

Click `CenterVertically` constraints and decrease `Multiplier` value to `0.4`. 
You can get answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786535/auto-layout-issue/48787434#48787434) that how to change multiplier value.

**LabelHolderView**

[image]

Add `UIView` for `Two Action` to `HolderView` called as `ActionHolderView`.

Give constraints for `ActionHolderView` as `left` and `right` 20px, `CenterVertically` and `Height` as 160px (approx)

Click `CenterVertically` constraints and increase `Multiplier` value to `1.3`.

Inside that `ActionHolderView`, drag Two `UIView` called as `PhotoView` and `NoteView` and Embed in `UIStackView` as `Horizontal` axis, Fill Equally and 8 as `Spacing`.

Give constraints for `UIStackView` as `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` as 0.

**ActionHolderView**

[image]

Change all `UIView's` `BGColor` as per your design. Then, add `UILabel` and `UIButton` and `UIImageView` to respective `UIViews`.

For UILabel, top, right, left and bottom as 0. (number Of lines as 2)

For Two UIButtons ,right, left and bottom as 8 and height as 30

For UImageView, Width and Height be 50px (Change width and height from Size Inspector - Square shape). Give Constraints as `CenterHorizontally`, `CenterVertically` and `AspectRatio` to its `SuperView` and `AspectRatio` to `itself`

**ViewController**

[image]

Comment: Your help is much much appreciated! I am sure I am going to have issues like this down the road, so do you have any guides, tools or suggestions on how to get better on this?

Comment: Am self learner ..!! I dont read any Tutorials for AutoLayout. My suggestion is, Just practicing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height/width constraints for your items. I would also put your add photo/add note buttons in a view to make it easier for constraints. Don't be afraid to mess around with it, you can always to command z to restore the previous version.